# Grammar To Parse Multiline Comments and String Literals Simultaneously

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, lexer

I am trying to parse C++/Java style source files and would like to isolate comments, string literals, and whitespaces as tokens.

For whitespaces and comments, the commonly suggested solution is (using ANTLR grammar):

```
// WS comments*****************************
WS: (' '|'\n'| '\r'|'\t'|'\f' )+ {$channel=HIDDEN;};
ML_COMMENT: '/*' (options {greedy=false;}: .)* '*/' {$channel=HIDDEN;};
SL_COMMENT: '//' (options {greedy=false;}: .)* '\r'? '\n' {$channel=HIDDEN;};
```

But, the problem is that my source files also consist of string literals e.g.

```
printf("   /* something looks like comment and whitespace \n");
printf("    something looks like comment and whitespace */ \n");
```

The whole thing inside "" should be considered a single token but my ANTLR lexer rules obviously will consider them a ML_COMMENT token:

```
    /* something looks like comment and whitespace \n");
printf("    something looks like comment and whitespace */
```

But I cannot create another lexer rule to define a token as something inside a pair of " (assuming the \" escape sequence is handled properly), because this would be considered as a string token erroneously:

```
/*  comment...."comment that looks */   /*like a string literal"...more comment */
```

In short, the 2 pairs /**/ and "" will interfere with one another because each can contain the start of the other as its valid content.  So how should we define a lexer grammar to handle both cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ***JavaMan wrote:***
>
> I am trying to parse C++/Java style source files and would like to isolate comment, string literal, and whitespace as tokens.

Shouldn't you match char literals as well? Consider:

```java
char c = '"';
```

The double quote should not be considered as the start of a string literal!

> ***JavaMan wrote:***
>
> In short, the 2 pairs /**/ and "" will interfere with one another.

Err, no. If a `/*` is "seen" first, it would consume all the way to the first `*/`. For input like:

```java
/*  comment...."comment that looks like a string literal"...more comment */
```

this would mean the double quotes are also consumed. The same for string literals: when a double quote is seen first, the `/*` and/or `*/` would be consumed until the next (un-escaped) `"` is encountered.

Or did I misunderstand?

Note that you can drop the `options {greedy=false;}:` from your grammar before `.*` or `.+` which are by default ungreedy.

Here's a way:

```java
grammar T;

parse
  :  (t=. 
       {
         if($t.type != OTHER) {
           System.out.printf("\%-10s >\%s<\n", tokenNames[$t.type], $t.text);
         }
       }
     )+
     EOF
  ;

ML_COMMENT
  :  '/*' .* '*/'
  ;

SL_COMMENT
  :  '//' ~('\r' | '\n')*
  ;

STRING
  :  '"' (STR_ESC | ~('\\' | '"' | '\r' | '\n'))* '"'
  ;

CHAR
  :  '\'' (CH_ESC | ~('\\' | '\'' | '\r' | '\n')) '\''
  ;

SPACE
  :  (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+
  ;

OTHER
  :  . // fall-through rule: matches any char if none of the above matched
  ;

fragment STR_ESC
  :  '\\' ('\\' | '"' | 't' | 'n' | 'r') // add more:  Unicode esapes, ...
  ;

fragment CH_ESC
  :  '\\' ('\\' | '\'' | 't' | 'n' | 'r') // add more: Unicode esapes, Octal, ...
  ;
```

which can be tested with:

```java
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String source = 
        "String s = \" foo \\t /* bar */ baz\";\n" +
        "char c = '\"'; // comment /* here\n" +
        "/* multi \"no string\"\n" +
        "   line */";
    System.out.println(source + "\n-------------------------");
    TLexer lexer = new TLexer(new ANTLRStringStream(source));
    TParser parser = new TParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    parser.parse();
  }
}
```

If you run the class above, the following is printed to the console:

```java
String s = " foo \t /* bar */ baz";
char c = '"'; // comment /* here
/* multi "no string"
   line */
-------------------------
```

```
SPACE      > <
SPACE      > <
SPACE      > <
STRING     >" foo \t /* bar */ baz"<
SPACE      >
<
SPACE      > <
SPACE      > <
SPACE      > <
CHAR       >'"'<
SPACE      > <
SL_COMMENT >// comment /* here<
SPACE      >
<
ML_COMMENT >/* multi "no string"
   line */<
```

Comment: Thanks, your're right. My misunderstanding of the way lexer rule work. BTW, is the ~('\r' | '\n')* in the SL_COMMENT equivalent to (~('\r' | '\n'))* ?

Comment: @JavaMan, yes, `~('\r' | '\n')*` is exactly the same as `(~('\r' | '\n'))*`

Comment: Is the OTHER lexer rule a must?  What would happen if a character cannot be matched with any of the lexer rules?

Comment: @JavaMan, the lexer would warn that is "sees" a character that was not matched by any of the lexer-rules. So yes, the `OTHER` rule must be in there.

Answer (score -4):

Basically your problem is: inside a string literal, comments (/* and //) must be ignored, and vice versa. IMO this can only be tackled by sequential reading. when walking through the source file on a character-by-character basis, you might approach this as a state machine with the states Text, BlockComment, LineComment, StringLiteral.

This is a hard problem to try to solve with regex, or even a grammar.

Mind you, any C/C++/C#/Java lexer also needs to handle this exact same problem. I'm quite sure it employs a state machine-like solution. So what I'm suggesting is, if you can, customize your lexer in this way.

Comment: *"This is a hard problem to try to solve with regex, or even a grammar."*, no it's not.  It can easily be translated into a couple of regular expressions: see my answer.

Comment: The high complexity of your answer caused me to provide this answer as an alternative. Yours might be a solution in this particular case, but it is not to be envied.

Comment: I disagree with the fact that my answer is complex: someone with just a basic knowledge of ANTLR can understand it. Besides, what you say is incorrect: the solution to the OP's problem are a couple regular expressions (the grammar is regular!).

Comment: It is correct, even in this case. But your solution works straightaway. Still, I find it construed. Agree to disagree.